Как сделать корректный запрос на получение сделок AMOCRM
Я создал несколько задач (сделок) в amocrm.
Далее мне нужно сделать js запрос за получение этих задач. Я это делал через fetch:
let dataObj = {};

async function isFetching(url){
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET', 
        mode: 'no-cors',
        headers: { 
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`, 
            'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
        } 
    })
    const data = await response.json();
    return data
}

    function createObj(data){
    dataObj.name = data._embedded.leads[0].name
    dataObj.id = data._embedded.leads[0].id
    dataObj.price = data._embedded.leads[0].price
    console.log(dataObj)
}

isFetching('https://followalex08.amocrm.ru/api/v4/leads').then(data => createObj(data))

И я запускал данный код на платформе NODE JS и мне приходит корректный ответ, и я вытаскиваю из него три поля (имя, id, и цену). Но данный запрос в браузере падает с ошибками.
И проблема в том, что далее мне нужно то, что я записал в этот dataObj (имя айди и цену). Добавить в верстку (карточки на сайте). Но как это сделать я не понимаю, так как браузер данный запрос не выполняет и падает с ошибкой.

браузер данный запрос не выполняет и падает с ошибкой какой ошибкой?
